# Why is my interior mirror is shaking?

Tags: honda, shaking, fit, mirrors

I bought a nice mirror on Amazon and when I put it up on the mirror.  It is bigger than the original mirror. The bigger mirror has been really good until one day and whenever I drive the mirror shakes.  If you have a mirror on the right and left side, it looks fine and stable.

How can I make the mirror stop from shaking ? I tried to do many different methods but I am out of luck.

Answer (score 0):

You fitted a heavier mirror, so now you need a stronger mounting.

Comment: Strong mounting.  Do you have any examples ?  LIke buy a new mirror  ?

Comment: @PROBERT what I can buy in my locality is not always the same as yours, which is why shopping questions get closed… either pad each side to change the frequency or get a different mounting.